# Jenkins, escape space character in jenkinsfile pipeline

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

i have next stage in my jenkins pipeline.

```
stage('Test') {
        steps {
           bat "${KATALON} -noSplash -runMode=console -retry=0 -projectPath=${PRJ} -testSuitePath="Test Suites/IPM - REF" -executionProfile='CD2' -browserType='Web Service'"

        }
```

When i run this pipeline it give me error : Test suite 'Test' not found.

How can i escape space character in this case ?

Comment: You need to escape your inner `"` and not the space, and you do it in the normal way with a backslash.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Didnt get it. Could you please show it in the command example ?

Answer (score 1):

Try triple quotes:

```
stage('Test') {
        steps {
           bat """${KATALON} -noSplash -runMode=console -retry=0 -projectPath=${PRJ} -testSuitePath="Test Suites/IPM - REF" -executionProfile='CD2' -browserType='Web Service'"""

        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Now its complaining >> -browserType='Web Service'.
Again Jenkins see it as seperate "Web".

Already tried to change double quote to single but no result.

Answer (score 0):

```
> bat """${KATALON} -noSplash -runMode=console -retry=0 -projectPath=${PRJ} -testSuitePath="Test Suites/IPM - REF" -executionProfile="CD2" -browserType=\"Web Service\""""
```

By this way my command was succeed. Thanks to all comments.